# Should I use a composite standard deviation for these multiple biological/technical replicates?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, composite

I used an ELISA to determine protein concentration from absorbance readings, which is a nonlinear relationship. I have 3 sample types, which are broken down into 3 biological replicates (per sample), and 2 technical replicates per biological rep. This gives 18 total values per each sample, as each technical rep possesses a mean with two different standard deviations, such that an example technical replicate data set might be (200, 300, 600). The middle value was the mean absorbance reading converted into pg/mL, while the 200 and 600 refer to the converted protein concentrations when the standard deviation of the absorbance is used - as I said, a nonlinear relationship. As I said, each bio replicate has six values, and each total sample type has 18.

Example data:
Untreated 1: (200, 300, 600)  (300, 400, 800)
Untreated 2: (two data sets similar to those above)
Untreated 3: (two data sets similar to those above)

I want to condense the 18 values into one mean and one standard deviation for each sample type, such as Untreated. How do I do this?

Comment: Typically it's adequate and standard practice to average the technical replicates for each biological sample and start from there, but it would help to know a bit more about your data first, in particular the relative scales of variability. Technical SDs of individual determinations are evidently on the order of a few hundred units. What are typical observed differences between 2 technical replicates on the same biologic sample? What is a typical SD between biologic samples treated the same way? What's the magnitude of the differences among sample types/treatments?